# Can POSIX filesystem ACLs grant group/world write privileges on a file with mode `0600`?

Tags: unix, permissions, filesystems, posix, acl

Given a POSIX-compatible Unix system (e.g. OS X, Linux, FreeBSD) with
filesystem ACLs enabled, and a regular file with permissions mode
`0600`, are there any access rules that can grant group or world write
privileges to the file despite the file mode?

I know it is possible to further restrict privileges on a file, but I
can not tell if the opposite is true.

Answer (score 1):

More testing tells me that this is indeed possible, which is quite
unsettling, given the lack of a real POSIX standard, non-C APIs, and
common userland tools.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but in a roundabout way:  Giving each user, and group, write access through the ACLs.

Comment: OS X: `chmod +a "group:everybody allow write,delete" private.db` is effectively world write. I had hoped that POSIX mode bits would work like umask WRT ACLs: process umask 0077 enforces owner-only privileges no matter what a program may dictate; wouldn't it be nice if ACLs respected mode bits in the same way? That way, a system that wants to use ACLs only can just set file modes universally to 0777 (effectively like NTFS)